# TNS connection forward

Tags: linux, oracle-12c, remote, sysdba, ssh

There are 3 machines as follows:

**Machine A** - Remote Exadata DB machine
**Machine B** - Remote machine from which only I can connect to port 1521 of Machine A
**Machine C** - Local Machine (To run SQL Developer and can't connect machineA directly)
**Machine D**  - Bastion Server through which I connect to Machine B

**Machine C** can access service running in **Machine B** only using SSH tunnelling.

Is there any way I can access the **Exadata DB from Machine A** using **SQL Developer running in Machine C**?

I am trying this way:

```
ssh MachineD -L 15219:MachineB:15220 -L 15220:MachineA:1521
```

which is not working.

Comment: how do you connect ti the exadata at the moment. Using sqlplus from machine B? If so, how do you connect to machine B?

Comment: @miracle173 yes , using sqlplus from machineB, From MachineC I use this: ssh MachineD -W MachineB:22 to login

Comment: did my solution work?

Comment: @miracle173, thank you for the detailed solution. Actually I am seeing some firewall issue, where connection is getting refused while accessing the port after creating the tunnel.

Answer (score 1):

You tried

```
ssh MachineD -L 15219:MachineB:15220 -L 15220:MachineA:1521
```

this did not work but you think in the right direction, you want to join two tunnels.

login to MachineD and make a tunnel from your MachineB port 15219 to MachineB port 15220

```
ssh -L 15219:MachineD:15220 MachineD
```

So If you now send something to MachineC port 15219 then your ssh session (from MachineC to MachineD) sends it to MachineD port 15220

if you do a

```
tnsping  '(DESCRIPTION =(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = MachineC)(PORT = 15219))(CONNECT_DATA = (SERVICE_NAME = ORCL)))'
```

you will get an error message

```
TNS-12541: TNS:no listener
```

or something similar, if you try to connect with SQL Developer.

Because if you now send something to MachineC port 15219 then your ssh session (from MachineC to MachineD) sends it to MachineD port 15220. And on  MachineD port 15220 there is actually nobody listening.

Now in your ssh session on MachineD execute the following command

```
ssh -L 15220:MachineA:1521 MachineB
```

Now you have opened an ssh session from MachineC to MachineB and data sent to MachineD port 15220 is read by this second ssh session and sent to MachineA port 1521. So you have two ssh sessions and the second one extends the first one.

But instead of opening one ssh session and in this ssh session opneing the other one you can do this in one command

```
ssh -L 15219:MachineD:15220 MachineD ssh -L 15220:MachineA:1521 MachineB
```

by juxtaposing both commands. If after an ssh command follows another comman this command is executed after login.
To avoid an error message like

```
Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.
```

you can use the `-T` option for the second `ssh`` command.

```
ssh -L 15219:MachineD:15220 MachineD ssh -T -L 15220:MachineA:1521 MachineB
```

If you get some

```
bind: Address already in use
channel_setup_fwd_listener: cannot listen to port: 15220
```

messages then change the adresses.

e.g. use  15221 instead of 15220. Of course you must replace it on both posisitions:

```
 ssh -L 15219:MachineD:15221 MachineD ssh -T -L 15221:MachineA:1521 MachineB
```

I hope this works. It is possible to configure the ssh daemons such that local forwarding is not allowed.

You cann concatenate an arbitrary number of tunnels .

I cannot test the -W option because I get

```
SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.3

Protocol mismatch.
```

Answer (score 0):

You said it yourself: SSH tunneling.

On machine C:

```
ssh -L 12345:machineA:1521 machineB
```

Then use localhost:12345 in SQL Developer.

With the above, you log in to Machine B from Machine C using SSH, and create a tunnel to the listener port of Machine A through Machine B.

Comment: To create a tunnel from MachineC to MachineB I have to use a bastion server.  e.g. ssh <bastion> -L 12345:MachineB:<serviceport> , then . how to use MachineA here ?

Comment: @kumarprd If you have another question then post a new question

Comment: @miracle173 this reply is related to the same question, if you have read it. I just mentioned the step, that I use to create the tunnel, as the step in the answer is not helping.

Comment: @kumarprd even if it is related it is a different one. So why not follow the policy of this site and post another question?

Comment: @miracle173 its not different at all. Try to understand the question and reply.

Comment: I am trying this way : 
`ssh MachineD -L 15219:MachineB:15220 -L 15220:MachineA:1521` which is not working.

Comment: I see now that you wrote "Machine C can access service running in Machine B only using SSH Tunneling." I think this refers to the bastion server you mentioned above.